# Select data from two dataframes into two dataframes with Pandas DataFrame and Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, like below

**rows_df**

```
  Id Location Age
0  0           30
1  1       US  20
2  2
```

**requiredCols_df**

```
  RequiredColumn
0       Location
```

`requiredCols_df` specifies which column is required in `rows_df`.
In this example, `Location` is required, `Age` is optional in `rows_df`.

I want to filter the `rows_df` based on the `requiredCols_df`. So there will be two resulting dataframes. One contains rows that have the required columns, and the other dataframe contains rows that don't have any required columns.

**Expected Result**

Rows matched

```
  Id Location Age
1  1       US  20
```

Rows don't match

```
  Id Location Age
0  0           30
2  2
```

Please note that:

1.The `rows_df` contains more than two columns, e.g. 10-30 columns.

2 The `requiredCols_df` contains more than one row.

3 Please note that `Location` contains a ' ' (empty space(s)) in row `0`, and a `null` (empty) in row `2`.

```
rows_df = pd.DataFrame({'Id':['0','1','2'],
                    'Location': [' ', 'US', None], 
                        'Age':['30','20','']})
```

column names below specify which column in `rows_df` must be not empty

```
requiredCols_df = pd.DataFrame([['Location']],
                            columns= ['RequiredColumn'])
```

**4 Update:** Both the resulting DataFrame contain the original non-changed values.

I can do this with a loop, but I want to see if there is a better solution.

Comment: There will be two resulting dataframes. One contains rows that have the required columns, and the other dataframe contains rows that don't have the required columns.

Comment: `null` isn't a python value, do you mean `None` or `''`?

Comment: empty cell (`None` in Python) or cell contains empty space '     '

Answer (score 1):

If you correct those to be true nans...

```
req_cols = requiredCols_df.RequiredColumn
rows_df[req_cols] = rows_df[req_cols].replace([r'^\s*$', '', None], np.nan, regex=True)

  Id Location Age
0  0      NaN  30
1  1       US  20
2  2      NaN
```

Then this is simple:

```
matched = rows_df.dropna(subset=req_cols)
not_matched = rows_df[~rows_df.eq(matched).all(axis=1)]
print(matched)
print(not_matched)

# Output:
  Id Location Age
1  1       US  20

  Id Location Age
0  0      NaN  30
2  2      NaN
```

---

Generalized:

```
rows_df = rows_df.replace([r'^\s*$', '', None], np.nan, regex=True)
matched = rows_df.dropna(subset=requiredCols_df.RequiredColumn)
not_matched = rows_df[~rows_df.isin(matched).all(axis=1)]
```

Comment: this seems most practical and can be extended for and to detect additional improper values

Comment: `df.replace([' ', '', None], np.nan)` we don't know how many empty spaces each cell might contains. Can it handle a cell that might contain many empty spaces?

Comment: @Pingpong, yes, set `regex=True` and use `r"\s*"` https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html

Comment: @ti7 You'll want `\s+`, otherwise it'll match everything~

Comment: ah, woops, start and end `r"^\s*$"`

Comment: ` df.replace(['\s+', '', None], np.nan, regex=True)`,  does it change all cells? Will it run faster if it only changes the mandatory columns only, if it is possible?

Comment: @Pingpong Updated to only fix "required" columns. But tbh, `replace` should be fast enough that it doesn't have a big impact, and there are benefits to fixing all these values in your data for future use~

Comment: @BeRT2me thanks for your answer. Is it possible to return the original value for the invalid data frame? That is,  any `Location` that has empty space should remain in the result.  As this is one of the requirements of the project (Not me). I added this to the update. Sorry for missing it.

Comment: pls keep your previous answer for which others find helpful, and add the new solution, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have a *tremendous* count of columns are there, this seems like a task for a loop

```py
df_result = rows_df
for column in requiredCols_df["RequiredColumn"]:
    df_result = df_result[df_result[column].notnull()]
```

Answer (score 0):

With this setup:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


rows_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Id": [0, 1, 2],
        "Location": [np.NaN, "US", np.NaN],
        "Age": [30, 20, np.NaN]
    }
)

requiredCols_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "RequiredColumn": ["Location"]
    }
)
```

We can easily form a boolean series to select what we want:

```py
required_column_not_null = rows_df[requiredCols_df["RequiredColumn"]].notnull().all(axis=1)

rows_df[required_column_not_null]
```

```
   Id Location   Age
1   1       US  20.0
```

---

```py
required_column_null = ~required_column_not_null

rows_df[required_column_null]
```

```
   Id Location   Age
0   0      NaN  30.0
2   2      NaN   NaN
```